# How to parallelize a nested for loop in python?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

Ok, here is my problem: I have a nested for loop in my program which runs on a single core. Since the program spend over 99% of run time in this nested for loop I would like to parallelize it. Right now I have to wait 9 days for the computation to finish. I tried to implement a parallel for loop by using the `multiprocessing` library. But I only find very basic examples and can not transfer them to my problem. Here are the nested loops with random data:

```
import numpy as np

dist_n = 100
nrm = np.linspace(1,10,dist_n)

data_Y = 11000
data_I = 90000
I = np.random.randn(data_I, 1000)
Y = np.random.randn(data_Y, 1000)
dist = np.zeros((data_I, dist_n)

for t in range(data_Y):
    for i in range(data_I):
        d = np.abs(I[i] - Y[t])
        for p in range(dist_n):
            dist[i,p] = np.sum(d**nrm[p])/nrm[p]

    print(dist)
```

Please give me some advise how to make it parallel.

Comment: In the code it looks like `dist[i,p]` gets fully written every step of `t`.  I don't see any dependencies on previous steps of `t`, so you only need to compute at `t=data_Y[-1]`... or is this supposed to be `dist[i,p] +=` not just `=`?  I ask because it's important to understand what sections can be run in parallel and which ones are dependent, thus need to be run serially.

Comment: @bivouac0 Yes, you are right. I forgot to mention that `dist` gets printed to a file for every `t`. So it gets filled for every `t` and not only for `t=data_Y[-1]`. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a small overhead with initiating a process (50ms+ depending on data size) so it's generally best to MP the largest block of code possible.  From your comment it sounds like each loop of `t` is independent so we should be free to parallelize this.

When python creates a new process you get a copy of the main process so you have available all your global data but when each process writes the data, it writes to it's own local copy.  This means `dist[i,p]` won't be available to the main process unless you explicitly pass it back with a return (which will have some overhead).  In your situation, if each process writes `dist[i,p]` to a file then you should be fine, just don't try to write to the same file unless you implement some type of mutex access control.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np

data_Y = 11 #11000
data_I = 90 #90000
dist_n = 100
nrm = np.linspace(1,10,dist_n)
I = np.random.randn(data_I, 1000)
Y = np.random.randn(data_Y, 1000)
dist = np.zeros((data_I, dist_n))

def worker(t):
    st = time.time()
    for i in range(data_I):
        d = np.abs(I[i] - Y[t])
        for p in range(dist_n):
            dist[i,p] = np.sum(d**nrm[p])/nrm[p]
    # Here - each worker opens a different file and writes to it
    print 'Worker time %4.3f mS' % (1000.*(time.time()-st))


if 1:   # single threaded
    st = time.time()
    for x in map(worker, range(data_Y)):
        pass
    print 'Single-process total time is %4.3f seconds' % (time.time()-st)
    print

if 1:   # multi-threaded
    pool = mp.Pool(28) # try 2X num procs and inc/dec until cpu maxed
    st = time.time()
    for x in pool.imap_unordered(worker, range(data_Y)):
        pass
    print 'Multiprocess total time is %4.3f seconds' % (time.time()-st)
    print
```

If you re-increase the size of data_Y/data_I again, the speed-up should increase up to the theoretical limit.

Comment: Why don't you pass arguments like `I` or `Y` to  `worker()`. Why is that not necessary?

Comment: When multiprocessing forks a new process, you get a copy of the current process, which includes all it's data (`I` and `Y` are globals and so are accessible to the worker function),  You can pass them as arguments but that's not required and will force them to be `pickled` which imposes some additional overhead.  It's probably good practice to put `global I, Y` at the top of `worker()` although it's not strictly required here.  I also see here that `dist` is defined globally.  It probably should be inside the `worker()`'