# How to stack sliding windows of several 1D signal toward a 2D matrix without for loop?

Tags: python, matrix, sliding-window

I made a code that makes a reshape of a 2D matrix with a sliding window.
I'm wondering if it is possible to do the same thing without the two nested for loop.
What I would like to have at the end is all sliding windows from all signals in a 2D matrix, where all windows from a signal is stacked contiguously in the final matrix.

```
nbSig = 3
fac = 10
size=5
k=0
Sigs = np.random.rand(nbSig,size*10)
s = np.zeros((nbSig * fac, size))

for j in range(nbSig):
    for i in range(fac):
        s[j * fac + i, :] = Sigs[j, k * fac + i:k * fac + i + size]
```

Comment: I think this question could be answered with a solution like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48710255/how-to-parallelize-a-nested-for-loop-in-python